# Is there a way to change only part of the layout when button is clicked in container view?

Tags: ios, layout

I'm new to iOS development using Swift. How can I change just the bottom layout with a container view so that, when Button A is clicked, the button layout changes and shows the "A" detail page, while the top layout still exists, like in this image:

[image]

Comment: Yes you can add navigation controller in container view, and push view controller on button click.

Comment: have you example about that? thanks @MatrixRevolved

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on this kind implementation there is so much responsibility for your view controller have to handle. In place of adding many responsibilities to one view controller, you can distribute the responsibility to multiple controllers. To achieve this add container view at the bottom and add navigation controller as a subview.
[image]

```
UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoardName bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationViewController = [mainstoryboard
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
// place navigation controller inside content view
[self addChildViewController:navigationViewController];
navigationViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
[self.containerView addSubview:navigationViewController.view];
[navigationViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @Queen Is it working for you still get some problem?

Answer (score 0):

Place a **container** **view** as bottom view. Embed the view controller of the container view in **navigation** controller. This will allow you to go to detail page and move backwards.

I have implemented this in a sample project. Download the sample project from my [**Github Repo**](https://github.com/AwaisFayyaz/SO-answer-Navigation-controller-in-containerView)

Note: BarTint of navigation bar is white (navigation controller)

---

Let  me know if you need any help.

See the sample execution.

[image]